# Python Flask render_template() ignore {{text}} that was not a var

Tags: python, templates, flask, render

I'm having a trouble using the render_template() Flask function.

In my original template (html) I have a 'text' that is wrapped by {{}}, and it should not be interpreted as a variable for flask to print. For example:

```
{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}
{{content.Name}}
```

In this particular case, flask is converting correctly the {{content.Name}} because it's an object that I'm giving as parameter in the render_template function. But the ERROR here is when the flask try to render {{InteractionDefaults.Email}} object, since that string is not a object that i'm giving as parameter, because it's a static text that should be printed exactly that way "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}" in the rendered template.

The error is:
'InteractionDefaults' is undefined

How can I say to flask do not interpreter this as a variable? I tried something like

```
@{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}
```

But I think that didn't work.

Comment: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/?highlight=raw#escaping

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the {{ by enclosing them in double quotes, for flask to interpret it as a string like,

`{{ "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}" }}`